# Getting rid of something from the memory?

Tags: python, memory

I'm not sure if this makes sense or if it is something you can actually do, so bear with me.

So I'm taking input from the commandline in python using the subcollections module. It's basically just a huge string with `\n` to indicate line breaks.

I then use parts of this string to create a list of data that I want.

Is there then a way to discard this huge string from the memory, basically telling memory that I don't need it anymore and it can throw it away?

Comment: Remove all references to it and the garbage collector should free it up automatically.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 so if I have `output = <huge string>` how do I remove the reference of `output` to it? Assign `output` to something else, like `output = 1`?

Comment: If the variable is still in scope, just delete it (e.g. `del output`).  If it fell out of scope, then it will be garbage collected automatically.

Comment: @Alexander Oh okay gotcha. So yea looks like the garbage collector got it automatically since it's out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Remove references, set null to them.

If you're in hurry, try calling directly (after remove references)

```
gc.collect()
```

If its local, when the function exits, your string shall be elegible to gc too.